# Simultanoeus http requests cause driver error of django pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I installed `MS ODBC Dirver for linux` and `pyodbc/django_pyodbc` for querying remote sqlsever databases. I used raw sql statements because I have limited permission for the DB.Everything was fine except:

One of the queries takes over 10 seconds to complete. Every time I try to make a another request from the browser( will execute another query statement ) before it's completed, an error occurs like this:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://9.123.108.155:8000/wsus/disconnected/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'debug_toolbar')
Installed Middleware:
(u'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_pyodbc/base.py" in _cursor
  290.             if self.ops.sql_server_ver < 2005:
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_pyodbc/operations.py" in _get_sql_server_ver
  32.         ver_code = cur.fetchone()[0]
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in inner
  106.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in inner
  106.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_pyodbc/base.py" in fetchone
  458.         row = self.cursor.fetchone()

Exception Type: Error at /wsus/disconnected/
Exception Value: ('IM001', '[IM001] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver does not support this function (0) (SQLGetData)')
```

In fact,it fails when django_pyodbc tries to get the version code of the sqlserver database. But that doesn't make sense because this error will not occur if no other query is ongoing. I'm pretty sure the DSN and the statements are valid.

views code: (I save the query statements in another file)

```
def report(request,db,report):
    cursor = connections[db].cursor()
    rows = cursor.execute(statements[report]).fetchall()
    cols = [ x[0] for x in cursor.description ]
    context = { 'rows':rows, 'cols':cols }
    return render(request, 'secport/report-ajax.html', context)
```

DB Settings:

```
'wsus':{
    'ENGINE':'django_pyodbc',
    'NAME':'SUSDB',
    'HOST':'xx.xx.xx.xx',
    'USER':'user',
    'PASSWORD':'password',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
    },
```

If my understanding is right, the requests should be isolated in different threads and not affect each other.Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.The reason is simple.Just deploy the App with Apache or any other web server, this error will be gone. I guess it's about the multiprocess.